# How to Push android Mobile app to US Google Play store

Tags: android, google-play

We release a mobile application last week & for some reason it is not showing up in US Google Play store.

How can we Push It to US Google Play store.

When we publish an App on Google Play Store by default it should show up in all store or we have to manually choose each store it should be available on

Comment: Did you select all countries while uploading apk

Comment: We had outsource this project & apk was published by them. Can we change it after app is available on google play store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to all countries in developer console.

[image: See The image]

Comment: Thanks, I did that & selected all countries. It should be available in few hours on all stores.